# How to manually build Expression which will return always true?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I tried to create Expression, but failed.

I want to build something like `Expression<Func<typeof(type), bool>> expression = _ => true;`

My attempt:

```
private static Expression GetTrueExpression(Type type)
{
    LabelTarget returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(bool));
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");

    var resultExpression = 
      Expression.Return(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(true), typeof(bool));

    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool));

    return Expression.Lambda(delegateType, resultExpression, parameter); ;
}
```

Usage:

```
var predicate = Expression.Lambda(GetTrueExpression(typeof(bool))).Compile();
```

But I am getting the error: `Cannot jump to undefined label ''`

Comment: You might try using `PredicateBuilder` by the Albahari Brothers. `var expr = PredicateBuilder.True<T>();` http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Comment: `typeof(type)` in your expression will *always* return `Type`

Comment: This works too: `public static Expression GetTrueExpression<T>() => Expression<Func<T, bool>>)(x => true); var predicate = GetTrueExpression<Object>();`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
private static Expression GetTrueExpression(Type type)
{
    return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Parameter(type, "_"));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had to face the same issue, and got this code.
It seems to be clean and simple.

```
Expression.IsTrue(Expression.Constant(true))
```

Comment: I have no idea. I think it's because my answer don't take a parameter.

Comment: I guess because OP is looking for a "callable generic function Expression" and this is just a "True" expression. Ivan Stoev's answer is clever. Creates an expression that represents a lambda, when you call the lambda expression with any type of parameter (just one) always returns true.