# Alternative expression that will always return true

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I am trying to build a dynamic `Expression<Func<User, bool>>` to use in MongoDB LINQ Where query filter.

I am building the expression dynamically using if-else blocks and combining the expressions using Albahari's `PredicateBuilder.And()` (http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Using `PredicateBuilder.True<T>()` among these `AND` blocks causes the MongoDB LINQ translator to throw this exception:

```
Unsupported filter: Invoke(f => True, {document}).
```

In what other expression format can I express `user=>true` kind of logic so that MongoDB LINQ provider will accept it?

Note: I tried using 
return Expression.Lambda(Expression.Constant(true), Expression.Parameter(type, "_"));
which I saw in another SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36773532/10811808) but I don't know how to convert this ConstantExpression to Expression>.

Comment: May be the problem is not with constant expression, but invocation (`Expresseion.Invoke`) used by the original `PredicateBuilder` implementation. You could try different `PredicateBuilder` implementations - for instance [Universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259 or similar

Comment: @IvanStoev You are exactly right, thanks. Using the Univeral PredicateBuilder solved the problem.